# What's the Correct Way of Selecting All List Items the React Way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to add hover event on each list item in my React/Gatsby App. When `li` item is hovered, I want to change the color of another element, the "Ball" element in this case.

So I'm setting reference to the parent `ul` like so:

```
let ulRef = useRef()
```

And add the reference to jsx:

```
<div>
  <div className="ball">Ball</div> // Element I want to change when li is hovered
  <ul ref={ulRef}>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What is the correct way of selecting all `li` elements? I tried using `querySelectorAll`:

```
let listItems = ulRef.current.querySelectorAll("li")
```

This seemed to work but after running the project again I get this error: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined`

Comment: To have more context what are you trying to accomplish with the hovering?

Comment: I want to change a color of another element. I will update my post to reflect this.

Comment: For example each list item contains a different color? and you would like to use that value to update another element?

Comment: Sort of. On hover of each list item, I want to change the background color of the  Ball div to diff color.

Comment: Avoid to use useRef() to operate Dom directly. In your case, you could use onMouseOver and onMouseOut event attach to each <li> to alter the state of color. And pass the state of color to the style of Ball

Comment: @Kuo-hsuanHsu I thought it was good practice to use `useRef` when working with DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments

> Sort of. On hover of each list item, I want to change the background color of the Ball div to diff color.

and

> Ok, thanks. I'm building a functional component so have to refactor your code.

I think this is as simple as it can get:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [ballColor, setBallColor] = React.useState();
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: ballColor }}>Ball</div>
      <ul>
        <li onMouseOver={() => setBallColor("purple")}>Purple</li>
        <li onMouseOver={() => setBallColor("orange")}>Orange</li>
        <li onMouseOver={() => setBallColor("lightgoldenrodyellow")}>Light Goldenrod Yellow</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: This is great. What if I have a SASS variable color I wanted to use? Should I set `ballColor` to a class, and change that class `onmouseover` ?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Just replace `style={...}` with e.g. `className={ballColor}` and ensure you have those classes declared in your SASS/CSS.

Comment: I'm using css-modules, and trying to implement using `className={`p-5 ${styles.ballColor`} }`. I thought that would work since `ballColor` is being changed to the class I want. Am I missing specific syntax? (comments wouldn't allow me to place appropriate back-ticks)

Comment: You'll want `styles[ballColor]` to index with a variable.

Comment: Looks like when I do `${styles.ballColor}`, `ballColor` is not recognized as a variable. So I'm thinking there's a syntax error. But how do I insert a variable within template literal? Ahh, you just answered my question above. Life saver, thanks!